# Is there a field like $\mathbb{C}$, but where the logarithm function is mostly continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The complex numbers live on a plane.  Their phase range is $0-2 \pi$.

This limited phase range makes logarithms have an irritating discontinuity.  The exponential function is periodic as you travel vertically along the imaginary axis.  That means $Exp[x]$ is not injective, so you can't invert it without kludges.

[image: Discontinuous logarithmic function]

Is there a way to change the set of complex numbers so that the logarithm function is mostly continuous?

Is there a structure that:

- "serves the purpose" of complex numbers we know today
- has a continuous logarithm function (or close)
- Bonus: is algebraically closed (or something like that)

A hypothetical example of an answer: "Instead of the complex-plane, you want the complex-helix [*this is a made-up concept*].
Unlike the complex plane where phases are limited to the range $0-2 \pi$, phases in the complex helix can by any real number.  The complex helix is a field.  Multiplication on the complex-helix is defined by multiplying the magnitudes and adding the phases.  Addition on the complex helix is defined by [????]".

Comment: FWIW, the "helix" of your hypothetical answer is the Riemann surface associated with the complex logarithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#The_associated_Riemann_surface

Comment: I just had the idea [on the complex helix thingy] that I know what I want the logarithm function to look like, and I know what I want multiplication to look like, so maybe I can define addition with $a + b = \ln[\exp{a}*\exp{b}]$.  Playing around with that.

Comment: You could look at, e.g., a differentially closed field with the Kolchin topolgy, but that is way larger than just $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I guess in order to define addition on $R$ in terms of $\ln$ and $\exp$, you still need to define $\ln:R\to R$ and $\exp:R\to R$. The construction only provides nice functions $\ln:R\to \Bbb C$ and $\exp:\Bbb C\to R$.